# XML Not Well-Formed

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm attempting to scrape some data from a webpage based off of a get request. I had a question similar to this not long ago and a user was able to show me how to parse an XML response. I went about using the same strategy but I am getting a 'not well-formed' error. I have searched for workarounds or solutions but I am not really getting anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My code is as follows:

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import json

base_url = "https://www.gmeiutility.org/actions/Search/?isPendingValidationChecked=true&isSearchAllLOUChecked=true&keyWord=5493&page=1&resultsPerPage=15&searchType=baseSearch&sortDirection=&sortFieldName="
r = requests.get(base_url)
print(r.content)


root = ET.fromstring(r.content)
data = json.loads(root.text)

for result in data['entitySearchResult']:
    print(result['LEINumber'])
```

Comment: My error looks like this:  xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

skip the `root = ET.fromstring(r.content)`. Not needed. Go straight to the 'json.loads'

```
import requests 
import json

base_url = "https://www.gmeiutility.org/actions/Search/?isPendingValidationChecked=true&isSearchAllLOUChecked=true&keyWord=5493&page=1&resultsPerPage=15&searchType=baseSearch&sortDirection=&sortFieldName=" 
r = requests.get(base_url) 
#print(r.content)

data = json.loads(r.content)

for result in data['entitySearchResult']: 
    print(result['LEINumber'])
```

I got output:

```
549300FTQBLOETQK6X43
549300UQLV7M883Z2X56
5493003MO7QE8VJUEP94
549300GKNMWK6EJZWB62
...
```

EDIT: If someone wants to expand/clarify beyond, feel free. My explination below might not be entirely accurate (and a poor explanation) because I'm still learning, but I think it has something to do with how the xml is structured with the `requests.get()`.

What I did, is I looked at your `r.content`, and it looked to already be in a json like structure, so I figured to try the `json.loads(r.content)` straight away.

Looking into it further, if you look at your previous post/question you posted (as you refered to above), when you `print (r.content)`, you'll see:

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"Result":[{"Appl_Number":"20181458","Seq_Num":"28","Inst_Rle_Cde":"1","Appl_Type":"BRANCH","Appl_Recd_YMD":"11/1/2018 12:00:00...
```

Notice it starts with `b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n`, so doing the `root = ET.fromstring(r.content)` in your first post, then looking at `root.text`, appeared to convert that in a way to what you `request.get()` here.

when you do the `print (r.content)` here, I see:

```
b'{"totalPages":28085,"totalResults":421274,"lastResult":15,"entitySearchResult":[{"isPendingReview":"false","headquartersAddressLineOne":
```

which is missing the `<?xml version="1.0"...>`  So I think that's why you were getting that error, because it was looking for `<?xml version="1.0"...>` when getting that `root = ET.fromstring(r.content)` So it couldn't convert it (or actually, all ready to use the `json.loads()` without doing the convert before it.

Like, I said, I'm still learning too, so I'll be doing some more looking into this and how XML works. None-the-less, it's a good starting point to look into, play around, and learn.

Comment: Thank you so much. Why is the 'root' part not necessary?

Comment: check the edit above. Basically, I think it's already in the format needed. Don't need to convert to the "root". My advice, look at your content from the previous post you asked, and compare it to this one (that's sort of what I did).

Comment: That makes sense. I did compare the two outputs between my questions and did notice that. I'm pretty new at this so I didn't quite know what the difference meant in terms of mining the data. Thanks again, I appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm right with you, fairly new too (especially with xml) with web scraping, but I think it's fun. I've been working/learning mostly with parsing html and json, so this was a good experience to look at xml a little bit. Just keep practicing, keep learning. It gets easier.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've been having a lot of fun with it, it's been very rewarding.